# Swift: How can I use UISearchResultsUpdating on child values of structs in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

In this UITableViewController I have an array of structs as such:

```
struct UserItem {

let key: String!
let displayName: String!
let profilePictureUrl: String!
let ref: Firebase!

    init(snapshot: FDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        displayName = snapshot.value["displayName"] as! String
        profilePictureUrl = snapshot.value["profileImage"] as! String
        ref = snapshot.ref
    }
}
```

and I have a search bar that uses the UISearchResultsUpdating class with the function:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
```

what I'm trying to do is filter out an array of the UserItem object using NSPredicate in the search bar on the UserItem.displayName property.

My most recent attempt is to put all the .displayName values in a [String] array and filter that into a new [String] array, but that seems a little messy to me. I want to simply filter the [UserItem] array.

I need the UserItem arrays so that I can compare unique user ID's in my segue to the user profiles.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use a predicate? If not, you can easily filter the array of structs with a closure as follows:

```
let filteredUserItems = userItems.filter { return $0.displayName.lowercaseString.containsString(searchValue.lowercaseString) }
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I have been scouring the internet for, THANK YOU SO MUCH.